# Script used to run `run-parts` for portmapping using Java program upon failover doesn't work

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# Setup portforwarding on router depending on interface running scripts from a directory 10.0.0.30 being eth0 represented by folder 30 and 10.0.0.31 being wlan0 represented by folder 31
eth0_status=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate)
wlan0_status=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate)
if [ "$eth0_status" = "up" ] && [ "$wlan0_status" = "down" ] ;
    then
      CURRDEV=eth0
fi  
if [ "$eth0_status" = "down" ] && [ "$wlan0_status" = "up" ] ;
    then
       CURRDEV=wlan0
fi
if [ "$eth0_status" = "down" ] && [ "$wlan0_status" = "down" ] ;
    then
       CURRDEV=
fi
if [ "$CURRDEV" = "eth0" ] ;
    then
       run-parts "/opt/portmapper/30"
       echo "Current device Ethernet"
elif [ "$CURRDEV" = "wlan0" ] ;
     then
       run-parts "/opt/portmapper/31"
       echo "Current device WiFi"
else
   echo "No changes need to be made to port mappings"
fi
```

Script currently works but for it to be less load I need variable checking to prevent the run-parts from executing every time the script runs. I only need it to run once when the device changes from one to another and not repeatedly every time I state of portmappings by running the script.

Example of port mapping script i have in the /opt/portmapper/30|31 directory directory 30 or 31 are the ethernet devices set eth0 or wlan0 respectively.

```bsh
 #!/bin/sh
    exec java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -add -protocol TCP -internalPort 443 -externalPort 443 -ip 10.0.0.30 ; sleep 2 ;
 fi
```

I originally pulled it from this working script in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/  - the else part does not work. I have to work on that too.  Notice this part has [[]] instead of []. If I place single brackets here script does not work.

```bsh
 #!/bin/bash
 # Enable/disable wlan0 depending on eth0 and wlan0 current state
 eth0_status=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate)
 wlan0_status=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate)
 if [[ "$eth0_status" = "up" ]];
     then
      nmcli con down id "wlan0"
 elif [[ "$wlan0_status" = "down" ]] && [[ "$eth0_status" = "down" ]];
   then
    nmcli con up id "wlan0"
 else
    nmcli nm eth0 on
    nmcli nm wlan0 off
 fi
```

Comment: Those "+x" look weird to me.

Comment: The first two check what a variables says about the states of the nic. If the variable is unset; it sets them before proceeding to last two which run commands based on variables settings.

Comment: I doubled the & and changed one of the variables of currdev and it still faults. Its the first two lines that are causing the problems. Multiple "if"s maybe?

Comment: after running the script removing those sections it still does not set eth0_status or wlan0_status. check by running echo $wlan_status and echo eth0_status in command line. I have also failed over the eth0 line by removing it and having it fail to wifi. ran this command as root ./mapcheck.sh and it does just pushes out the else echo string on the bottom. I read somewhere I might need to double the brackets is that true?

Comment: I failed to mention that i removed that section. I removed them in the file and re-ran. Now it just says the "else echo No changes need to be made to port mappings" set currdev=wlan0 and ran the file and even failed over to wifi. it still just else echo No changes need to be made to port mappings. I will edit code to what I currently have.

Comment: did those in the file. Still return the else echo at the bottom.

Comment: Also could you please remove all your comments until now? They're not relevant anymore, and comments shouldn't be used for extended discussion.

Comment: currdev set the device to either wlan0 or eth0 so the script does not loop. Am I wrong by doing this. I thought I was doing this to prevent loop protection on the script so it does not continously run the java scripts in the run-parts over and over again unless it needs to.

Comment: So how do I stop this script from continually running over and over again so it does not hammer the router with port mapping requests? Place this at the before the first if? BTW it work. Buts its hammering my router.     if [ "$eth0_status" = "up" ] && [ "$wlan0_status" = "down" ] ;
   then
      currdev = eth0
if [ "$eth0_status" = "down" ] && [ "$wlan0_status" = "up" ] ;
   then
      currdev = wlan0

Comment: the java scripts in /opt/portmapper/31 on the run-parts section are running over and over again every 5 minutes as i have it set it on crontab -e */5 * * * * root /opt/portmapper/mapcheck.sh . Setting the currdev stops the processing of the latter sections (run-parts/echo/currdev=wlan0|etho) over and over below and just ends the script.

Comment: I do not want the router to be hammered by scripts from this program. http://upnp-portmapper.sourceforge.net/ that are located in /opt/portmapper/31 and /opt/portmapper/30

Comment: Ohh current device that is in operation to supply connectivity between the two eth0 and wlan0. I have a failover setup between eth0 and wlan0 where eth0 is primary and take priority and turns off wlan0 when eth0 is active.

Comment: I will update OP.

Comment: ./mapcheck.sh: 24: ./mapcheck.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi") - added two more fi at end .. now I do not get the else echo.

Comment: bad fi placement. going to test the wifi failover now and AGAIN!

Comment: does not work. does not change the portmappings on wifi. Also just dumps to else echo at the bottom.

Comment: Okay so its not setting the variable $currdev.

Comment: I see it. I think. I just do not know how to change it now that you said it. I just dont know how to fix the if lines to remove it.

Comment: So its running but the problem is now that it will run every 5 minutes with no checks for the fail over. So it will do the run parts everytime.

Comment: I wonder I place this script in the /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ with the original script I wrote for the failover and will only run when a change of connectivity on the network interface happens that is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you want is to change the port mapping through `run-parts` each time the interface in use changes avoiding to run `run-parts` if the interface in use didn't change since the last time `run-parts` was run.

You'll need to store the last interface in use's status somewhere and each time the script is run compare the current interface in use against that somehow; this script does that (it updates the current interface in use in `/opt/mapper/prevdev` each time a change takes place):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
eth0_status=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate)
wlan0_status=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate)
touch /opt/portmapper/prevdev # Creates /opt/portmapper/prevdev if it doesn't exist
prevdev=$(cat /opt/portmapper/prevdev)
if [ "$eth0_status" = "up" ] && [ "$wlan0_status" = "down" ]; then # We're currently on Ethernet
    currdev=eth0
fi
if [ "$eth0_status" = "down" ] && [ "$wlan0_status" = "up" ]; then # We're currently on WiFi
    currdev=wlan0
fi
if [ "$currdev" != "$prevdev" ]; then # The interface in use has changed since the last time we checked
    if [ "$currdev" = "eth0" ]; then # We're currently on Ethernet
        run-parts /opt/portmapper/30
        echo 'Current device and portmappings are on Ethernet'
        echo 'eth0' >/opt/portmapper/prevdev # Updates /opt/mapper/prevdev
    else # We're currently on WiFi
        run-parts /opt/portmapper/31
        echo 'Current device and portmappings are on WiFi'
        echo 'wlan0' >/opt/portmapper/prevdev # Updates /opt/mapper/prevdev
    fi
else
    echo 'No changes need to be made to port mappings'
fi
```

Comment: ./mapcheck.sh: 17: ./mapcheck.sh: Syntax error: "else" unexpected (expecting "then")

Comment: If i change it to then it runs  the run-parts every time  on wifi with no variable check to stop it from running. - nevermind it had to set prevdev.

Comment: @VincentBird See the update, I forgot a `then` on line 12.

Comment: How do i mark this as sovled?

Comment: @VincentBird Click on the grey tick under the votes count on the left of the answer and it will turn green. That basically means the answer worked for you.

Comment: Thanks.. no only if I can get it to work in dispatcher.d along with the other script I wont have to do checking with root crontab every 5 minutes. Off to learn something. Thanks for your help.